# TypeScript: How to pass function-type member variable by reference?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, delegates, functor

I have an object with a function-type member variable, and a setter function which sets any given function-type variable of that same signature to some function:

```
class Foo {
    // This is the function that we want to set to something else
    public delegated: (param : string) => void 
        = () => { console.log("Default value, was not set to anything else."); };
}

// This a function we should be able to set Foo.delegated to, as it has the same signature
function printAllCaps(s : string) : void {
    console.log(s.toUpperCase());
}

// This is the function that does the setting. Currently, it doesn't work.
function setDelegateToPrint(delegate : (param : string) => void) {
    delegate = printAllCaps;
}

let myFoo : Foo = new Foo();

// We try to set it -- no effect.
setDelegateToPrint(myFoo.delegated);

myFoo.delegated("hello!");
```

The `setDelegateToPrint` function has no effect. I assume that is because `myFoo.delegatedFunction` was not passed by-reference, but rather by-copy. Possibly because we didn't pass `myFoo` in some way.

How can this be done? It *needs* to be done *without* passing `myFoo` as a `Foo`, because the setter function should not know the `Foo` class definition for encapsulation. It can only know the bare minimum required information: there is an object, and the object has a member function of a given signature.

Note: this code not fullfilling the needed task can easily be checked by copy-pasting the entire code into TypeScript playground and pressing "run".

Comment: What problem are you facing in your attempt?

Comment: What's the problem to do like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=9&module=100&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoaXoAcCuARiAJbDQAmApiJQOZgAul5seAdsA8fG9AFzQAFDjAAnMAFt+0CA1HE2tAJTQAvAD5oAN3jFyaoSo0oAvgG4MJjDQbQJATwRJV0NpQDucRIKUX0GBycAOioaeiYWdk5uXhdBMVoBWXlFI01kaGAeCHgaIJB4WnjRZSt-dEDEEOo6RmZWDi4eQQBycnaWpSA

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=9&module=100&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoaXoAcCuARiAJbDQAmApiJQOZgAul50AXNABQ5gBOYAtm2gQGPYgDtaASmgBeAHzQAbvGIsM2TXM4yFKaMHjiI8GgDoQ8WhwBEAEUoAzMHhANlYEHkoAaaAHdIaHF4dwhKdwYkMHEATwYACwlaaGpwsxspAG5oAF8sjFyMDEc8cWAGYiNcMXEGAEEQEABhMBwIDhh2EVrpIRU1FA1sQ2NTSgsrTrMogFUcHEoeVvCOKWzC4vRS8srq8IYHGnomABV4AAVahg5HRCEEeBk0TGw7+DMqY8ZmbRxrxotNoQAroIroDA0dz8WKPB73WTBSj+OCINagjAHI50H7nK4SG4wx4bCHoImIT7UHFMci2BLUSwAQkyWSAA

Comment: @Anatoly Thank you, but I am really trying to avoid having the setter function know of the object’s class type, as this approach has too many downsides. For one, the setter and object class are parts of entirely different systems that should not know of each other for proper encapsulation. Also, setter becomes less resuable, as for each class with functor of this signature you need a new setter. The intent is also way less readable if you pass the object: the setter is just “set any functor of given signature”, why it needs an object is confusing to a reader (because logically it doesn’t).

Comment: @caTS I now understand the problem better: it's necessary to store an object's function-type member variable in a generic way (i.e. without knowing anything else about the object's class, just that it has this variable of this type).

I assume regardless of language, storing/passing this requires two pieces of information: which object, and which variable. I haven't found a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This needs to be done without passing myFoo itself" - then, you can't.

What you could do is pass myFoo, but make `setDelegateToPrint` generic and accept one of its keys.

I changed a bit your code:

```js
// This class has not been changed
class Foo {
  public delegatedFunction: (param: string) => void = () => {
    console.log("Default value, was not set to anything else.");
  };
}

// Here I'm just ensuring the function is the same type
const printAllCaps: Foo["delegatedFunction"] = (s) => {
  console.log(s.toUpperCase());
};

// Here I added some type information so that the
// second parameter has to be a key of the first parameter
//
// NOTE: this can be improved, for example passing a third
// parameter which is the function (printAllCaps) and it
// must be of the same type of the method you're overriding.
// More on this later.
function setDelegateToPrint<O, K extends keyof O>(
  obj: O[K] extends Foo["delegatedFunction"] ? O : never,
  key: K
) {
  obj[key] = printAllCaps;
}

let myFoo: Foo = new Foo();

// Here I'm passing the key of the method to override, instead of passing the method itself
setDelegateToPrint(myFoo, "delegatedFunction");

myFoo.delegatedFunction("hello!");
```

---

This can be improved by passing a third parameter to `setDelegateToPrint` and making it even more generic:

```js
function setDelegateToPrint<O, K extends keyof O>(
  obj: O,
  key: K,
  overrideFn: O[K]
) {
  obj[key] = overrideFn;
}

setDelegateToPrint(myFoo, "delegatedFunction", printAllCaps);
```

---

FOOTNOTE:

be aware that you're mutating an object from a scope outside the function and it is not advisable at all, it will be hard to debug for sure.
Do this only if you're sure you **cannot avoid** that.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! You're right about the first statement you mention, I should have put it differently: without passing `myFoo` as a `Foo` specifically, but in a generic way, since the `setDelegateToPrint` is unaware and cannot be aware of the `Foo` class specifically, just that it is some object with a member of the needed type.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw I added a footnote since mutating an object from a scope outside the function should be avoided if possible

Comment: Why is mutating the object not advisable? I am asssuming, if it's the exact intent for the function-type member to be delegated to an outside implementation, that there is no other way? 

For a real-world example, let's say `Foo` needs to retrieve an access token, and the token can be provided by several sources. We have several `Foo`s out and about, and several token retrievers talking to different endpoints/APIs: we want to call one retriever's function when `myFoo1.getToken()` is called, and another one's when `myFoo2.getToken()` is called.  

How else would this be possible?

Comment: To explain, I am coming from a C++ background where saving functors is fairly common, and there is a variable type that is meant for the exact purpose of keeping a reference to a function elsewhere. So maybe the approach I'm taking in TS is informed by a paradigm that doesn't fit the language, as I'm not aware of best practices and functional programming approaches which allow flexbility and good encapsulation.

Comment: I'll have to expand on that then, I'll take some time later. In short: in functional programming mutation is avoided as much as possible (depending on the language, structures might be already immutable); anyway, in this case you could even extend Foo (`class FooUppercase extends Foo`) and override the method, then use `let myFoo2: FooUppercase = new FooUppercase(); myFoo2.delegatedFunction("hello!");` .